# Mathjax input applied from javascript script not working?

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax, tex

I have one simple Mathjax code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
  </script>
<script>
var ok = function ()
{
   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="$$10\\x^2$$"
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="ok()">Click</button>
<p id="demo1">Within html $$10\\x^2$$</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I was applied from direct html the Tex was converting.But applied from javascript its not rendering.What should i do.I was search with google but not getting answer.
I need to apply the latex code from javascript It will be rendered with Tex format.Anyone help me to solve my problem.Please give  a code its more help full for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
  </script>
<script>
var ok = function ()
{
   document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="$$10\\x^2$$"
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick="ok()">Click</button>
<p id="demo1">Within html $$10\\x^2$$</p>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is not exactly the same :/
But your problem is MathJax doesn't refresh when you change data dynamically.

Maybe take a look here : https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/test/sample-dynamic.html

I don't know this lib, can't help you more.

Comment: The backslashes need to be doubled in javascript text string literals (since the backslash is a special character in strings).  So you need `innerHTML="$$10\\\\x^2$$"` to get the same result as the original HTML.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.